# Doctrine count groupe By

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this query:

```
$sqlRequete = $bdd -> query("SELECT idJeu, COUNT(*) FROM documents_lignes GROUP BY idJeu ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 20");
```

How can I do this with Doctrine in a Symfony project ?
I have a table named documents_lignes with one jointure: boite (IdJeu)

Thank you

I have try this:

```
    public function findBoitesGroupeBy(){

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('dl')
            ->select('dl.boite, COUNT(dl.boite)')
            ->innerJoin('dl.boite', 'b')
            ->groupBy('b.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
```

But the result is not correct

Comment: Please add the expected result and explain what is not correct in the result of your Doctrine Query.

Comment: I want to have the list of the most boite in order of count. Now I have lot of array, without knowing wish boite is